# CakePHP 2 How to Add Parameters to $this->Auth->user()

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I've inherited a CakePHP 2.X project and I want to add more parameters to $this->Auth->user(). For example, I want to add an account name to the user data so I can retrieve it with $this->Auth->user('business_name');. Where do I do that?

Comment: `$this->Auth->user()` should return the user record of the logged-in user. So, it's the user record that needs to be updated. How to do that would depend on how you're handling users (e.g. custom code or a plugin).

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a plugin and there are some very specific entries like $this->Auth->user('franchise_id') and other entries from an _accounts_ table. I just can't find where that info is being set in the code.

Comment: Seems that you've got something custom, so the answer isn't going to be a stock one. Check the login function, any configuration provided to the Auth component, and search the entire codebase for references to `accounts`, `franchise_id` and any other fields from the accounts table that are referenced through Auth calls like this. Hopefully something relevant will catch your attention.

Answer (score 0):

When we want a user to be logged in we use this authentication function:

```
$this->Auth->login($user_data);
```

So this auth function will add $user_data as a parameter in the session so all that you need is to add new value to array $user_data.

Or if you want to add it after the login you can by writing to the session is this way:

```
CakeSession::write('Auth.User.business_name', 'your value here');
```

Hope this answers your question